# MacTeX 2011, Xetex and Tex Live Utility

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, mactex, xparse

I tried several times to play with XeLaTeX (being used to "classical" LaTeX) but since I installed MacTeX 2011 and updated it with TeX Live Utility, I got that kind message :

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty:57: U
ndefined control sequence.
<argument> \ExplFileName 

l.57 ...e}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}
```

If I continuously press "Return", I got a lot of error messages linked to Unicode font scripts, for instance :

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:1909: Undefi
ned control sequence.
l.1909 \newfontlanguage{Efik}{EFI}\newfontlanguage
                                              {Greek}{ELL}
```

I seems there is a problem between version of xparse, fontspec etc. But it occurs even after re-installing Tex Live and updating only one package not linked to xelatex or fonts. The log file is quite long with all these errors (about 4200 lines).

Could it be caused by the scripts run by tlmgr after updating a package?

Edit:Sorry for mistake about "answer".

Here is a link to the log file : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6420461/xelatex3.log

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Your version of `l3kernel` does not match that for `l3packages`. Try at the Terminal `sudo tlmgr update l3kernel` and `sudo tlmgr update l3packages`.

Comment: MacTeX also installs the TeX Live Utility. If you launch that it should tell you if anything else is out of date and help you to update everything. This is also a neat way of finding out about new packages.

Comment: (TL2011) I update this morning all the packages (Update all  packages)  with TeX Live Utility and my codes compile very well. Perhaps you can give a minimal working example.

Comment: I finally understood why update broke a working installation for xetex : the Tex Live Utility preferences "remove packages to match the server when updating" was not checked. So there was a conflict between expl3 and l3kernel. Thanks !

Comment: even i face same issues, xetex is broken with 2011 version.

Answer (score 3):

The log is exactly what I expected to see: a partly updated system. You need to remove the older `expl3` bundle and install `l3kernel`. You may also need ot remove the older `xpackage` bundle and replace with the newer `l3packages`. From the Terminal, `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` will do this.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and despite tlmgr not finding any updates available, the problem persists. Exact same causes, same error messages... The problem seems to be with sparse, which the tex live utility tells me is up to date